# how to get and display my site name from other table (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wanted to create a view that able to list all the site that the user have the admin rights.

How could I pass and show the site name in the view?
Let say I am user with id no 1, the view will show the site name that I have the admin rights.

I use people_site (admins) table to record all the rights.

```
sites table:
--------------------
id  | site_name | address 
101 | ABC       | 2131
102 | CDE       | 23212
103 | EFG       | 23231
104 | HIJ       | 1234

peoples table:
--------------------
id  | first_name | last_name | paswword
1   | Alex       | Lee       | *******
2   | Bryan      | John      | ******* 

people_site (Admin )table:
--------------------
id  | people_id | site_id
101 | 1         | 101
102 | 1         | 102
103 | 2         | 103
104 | 1         | 104
105 | 2         | 101
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getManage(){
    return View::make('account.manage')
        ->with('admins', Admin::where('people_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get());
}
```

**View:**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($admins as $admin)
    <li><a href="">{{$admin->id}} </a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

**People Models: **

```
public function sites(){
    return $this->hasMany('Site');
}
```

**Site Models:**

```
public function peoples(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('People');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a extra column for user type using id is not good have to user types/admin and normal and you can retrieve based on column type where type ="admin" , hope you got idea what I am saying.

Comment: Hi Shadow, actually the people table have more attribute such as password etc, now i added it. i think this is many to many relationship which 1 people can have many site to admin, and 1 site can have many people as admin

Answer (score 0):

Let say if the view has multiple users & multiple sites

```
<ul>
  @foreach($admins as $admin)
    <li><a href="">{{ $admin->id }} </a></li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        @foreach($admin->sites as $site)
          <li><a href="site/{{ $site->id }}">{{ $site->site_name }} </a></li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```